# Significance of the different designs of Tobi's/Obito's masks

Tags: naruto

There have been three designs of the masks of Tobi/Obito shown in the Naruto (anime/manga). Is there any significance behind the masks and the designs, or is it just a design and something to be ignored?
[image: mask-1]
[image: mask-2]
[image: mask-3]

Answer (score 3):

The masks in each stage has their own significance:

The **Spiral Mask** with center at the eye was designed by the mangaka to give the **dimension switch** by Tobi a better look.

The **Rinne-Sharingan** shaped mask was worn by Tobi during the Shinobi War to represent his mission i.e achieving the Rinne-Sharingan for the **Infinite Tsukuyomi** .

All these designs don't have any significance from the perspective of the storyline. They were just designed by the mangaka to have a stylish, appropriate appearance.

Source:

- [Obito Uchiha](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Obito_Uchiha)

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently the masks represent the different stages that Obito's eyes move to.

The third mask is obviously a combimation of the Sharingan with the Rinnegan. It is the same pattern that can be seen on the moon or on Kaguyas forehead.

The 2nd one is like a whirpool, which makes me think of Obito's power to suck other people in the other dimension, that looked kinda similar (look for instance the fight with the 4th Hokage)

The first one is the one I cannot identify. To me, initially, it kinda looks like the cursed pattern that Sasuke gets on his face, but that is kinda of forced, since it does not look exactly like that, and it has no relationship with Obito.

Answer (score 0):

The first mask is a reference to the 9 tails he summoned (referenced by the 9 ends to the lines on the mask)

The second is a reference to both his Kamui ability and Tobi (guruguru)

The third is a reference to the eye of the moon plan, the pattern is reminiscent of the rinne sharingan and also the third tamoe is in position for a third eye that Obito would have gained.

Comment: There is 8 lines on the mask ... am I wrong?

Comment: yea technically there are 8 lines but I was counting the ends on the lines. if you count the tips of the lines near the eye then you get 9. Although I admit this interpretation is a bit of a stretch is the only I could come up with.

Comment: ahan got it. anyway it's not good reason but can thing about it :-) Thank you so much for sharing your opinion

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just rotate it and then you have the first maks

Comment: That doesn't explain anything.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Tobi (Zetsu)]

I’m not 100% sure, since I’ve not finished the anime and haven’t read the manga, but I think the orange spiral pattern is related to the Zetsu named Tobi, nicknamed Guruguru by Obito.

Answer (score -1):

:spoiler:

I think the first mask is supposed to represent the mission that he was crushed under the rocks due to the creased pattern on the right side of the mask where his face was partially crushed, the second mask is to represent kamui which is the dimension switch ability of his mangankeyo sharingan, and the last mask is foreshadowing the rineesharingan which is a mix of the rinegan and sharingan.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.

Answer (score -1):

The first mask represents the Kyuubi's tails, the second either his Kamui ability or his friend Guruguru, and the third is related to his Tsuki no Me plan. :D